# Create List Based on Highlighted Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my example, I would like the chemical names of all red highlighted values (which are values above the screening value) to be put into a cell as a list.

For example, if arsenic, calcium, and nitrate are above the screening value, I would like a cell to auto populate =arsenic, calcium, and nitrate.

It doesn't matter if the highlighted value in columns labeled 1,2, or 3 are all highlighted or only one. I would like to capture any chemical names where at least one value is red.

|  |  | Screening Value | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chloroform | ug/L | 1.9 | 0.5 |  | 1 |
| Chloromethane | ug/L | 7000 | 0.5 |  | 2 |
| 4-Nitrophenol | ug/L | 0.016 |  | 5.1 | 4.5 |
| Benzo(a)anthracene | ug/L | 0.03 |  | 0.3 | 0.27 |
| Benzo(a)pyrene | ug/L | 0.0071 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.18 |
| Benzo(g,h,i)perylene | ug/L | 250000 |  | 0.51 | 0.45 |
| Dibenz(a,h)anthracene | ug/L | 70 |  | 0.51 | 0.45 |
| Hexachloroethane | ug/L | 0.024 |  | 3 | 2.7 |
| N-NitrosodimethyIamine (NDMA) | ng/L | 70 | 14 | 2 | 6.3 |
| N-Nitroso-di-n-propyIamine (NDPA) | ng/L | 140 |  | 10 | 10 |
| Phenanthrene | ug/L | 0.025 |  | 0.2 | 0.18 |
| Aluminum | ug/L | 1400 |  |  |  |
| Arsenic | ug/L | 0.61 |  |  |  |
| Calcium | mg/L | 0.0081 | 29 |  | 30 |
| Chromium-Hexavalent | ug/L | 1400 |  |  |  |
| Cobalt | ug/L | 300 |  |  |  |
| Copper | ug/L | 140 |  |  |  |
| Iron | ug/L | 11000 |  |  |  |
| Manganese | ug/L | 700 |  |  |  |
| Nickel | ug/L | 0.00024 |  |  |  |
| Sodium | mg/L | 0.0035 | 40 |  | 26 |
| Chloride | mg/L | 20000 | 78 |  | 36 |
| Nitrate | mg/L | NA | 1.5 |  | 1 |
| Nitrite | mg/L | NA | 0.01 |  | 0.01 |
| Acetaldehyde | ug/L | NA |  | 100 | 30 |
| Formaldehyde | ug/L | NA |  | 9.1 | 30 |
| Hydrazine | ug/L | NA |  | 0.05 | 0.05 |

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `FILTER` and `TEXTJOIN`?

Comment: How are the values highlighted? Manually or with conditional formatting?

Comment: With conditional formatting

Comment: @RachelGladstone posted some alternative solutions, definitely it will work, this is actually based on the values above the screening values. Do check in answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd>, <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> & <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A28,MMULT((D2:F28<>"")*
(D2:F28>C2:C28),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D2:F28),,,0))))
```

---

If you have only 3 Columns then use this one.

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H4</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A28,MMULT((D2:F28<>"")*(D2:F28>C2:C28),{1;1;1})>0))
```

---

Or, you can make this dynamic as well by adding another function within the <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> using <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A28,MMULT((D2:F28<>"")*(D2:F28>C2:C28),TOCOL(D1:F1)^0)>0))
```

---

Another alternative approach, you don't need a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions. The following formula ensures that, so that said <kbd>DROP( )</kbd> ensures to take always the first column from the range <kbd>C2:F28</kbd> while <kbd>TAKE( )</kbd> ensures to exclude the first column and take the rest. <kbd>REPT( )</kbd> returns a range of text values from column repeated, <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> transforms the repeated text arrays into a single column. <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> and <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> does the finishing work.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=LET(α,C2:F28,
        TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(TOCOL(REPT(A2:A28,N(DROP(α,,1)>TAKE(α,,1)))))))
```

---

With <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>,

```
=LET(α,C2:F28,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A2:A28,MMULT(N(DROP(α,,1)>TAKE(α,,1)),{1;1;1}))))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Similar yet another solution with 2 inputs:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A2:A28,BYROW(C2:F28,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(TAKE(x,,1)<TAKE(x,,-3)))))))
```

[image]